# How can I delete my own comment?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments

I wrote a comment, and now I would like to delete it, but I cannot find how to do this. How can I delete my comment?

Comment: There's an "x" icon when you hover over your comment. Click on it

Comment: Fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336916/4574

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to leave the comment so this is the only way **I can confirm the issue**. Someone who has enough reputation points to move the other's answers may remove this 'answer' and put the note in the appropriate place.

I can confirm I am experiencing the very same issue as the original poster explained in his question and again [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336797/how-to-delete-my-own-comment-on-stack-overflow#comment407115_336814) in his comment. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188883/processing-raw-data-read-from-serial-port-with-python-serial-library/40190787#comment67727340_40190787) are the comments where <kbd>X</kbd> or `delete` does not appear **on mouse over** so I cannot delete **my own** comments and neither could I edit them during the first 5 minutes after posting.

Here is the screenshot which **includes the cursor** so it can be seen there is nothing shown on mouse over:

[image]

Here is the picture where can be clearly seen the mouseover on **other's** comment works as expected:

[image]

The `upvote` and `flag` options do show if I hover the mouse over the comment **which is not mine** but the options to `delete` (or `edit` if there is still enough time left to edit the comment) do not show upon hovering the mouse over my own comments **anymore**.

Note: Although I don't have too many reputation points I certainly do remember how *editing/deleting 'own comments' function* worked before.

**Edit:**
Now, a few hours later, the function is working again:

[image]

[image]

During the time when it did not work the icon wasn't shown neither with FF nor with Chrome browser.

Comment: It was a bug - see the link under the Q...

Answer (score 5):

Take a look on this screenshot...

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

After your comment there have a small red circle with a cross sign, you can delete your comment using it...

See the image below:

> [image]

Comment: I still didn't see the red cross mark at the right of my comment. I was wondering whether only certain levels of users can delete their own comments.

Comment: i don't think so,however comment can be deleted

    A user can delete their own comment.

    A moderator can delete anyone's comments.

   Any user with at least 15 reputation can flag a comment, and enough flags can cause the deletion of that comment.

@Cirrus i think you confused with this,please look carefully your comment delete icon..and if you got any useful think from my answer,please up vote it,to upvote user must have more than 15 reputation,you have only 13,so then i'll give upvote your comment :)

Comment: Weird how difficult / impossible it is to delete your own answers.