# Changes to allow 15 rep dupe flagging might be preventing < 50 rep users to genuinely edit/delete their comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, automatic-comments

This is related to: [How to delete my own comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336797/how-to-delete-my-own-comment-on-stack-overflow) (the option to delete/edit seems to be missing or non-obvious...)

The common theme is that the users involved are < 50 rep and thus don't have the comment anywhere privilege. The recent changes to allow users to flag duplicates at 15 rep (instead of 50 rep because of the auto-comment) added some restrictions to negate the possibility of the user being able to abuse the auto-comment it now generates.

Is it possible this restriction is being a little over-zealous and isn't taking into account user comments that the OP is normally entitled to edit/delete on their own questions?

Comment: _"Good news everyone! You can now flag with 35 less rep! Oh, and your comments are now permanent, muahahaha!"_

Comment: This case (allow users to edit/delete own comments) was _supposed_ to have been taken in account. Taking a look

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My fault. When implementing that I thought "careful, users must still be able to edit and delete comments on their own posts" but missed the "...and comments on answers to their own questions" part. It should be fixed by now.